# Move a Perl script with dependencies from one computer to another

Tags: linux, perl, rhel

I have a Perl script on an old RHEL4 x86_64 Linux computer. This script runs only on this computer, and we'd like to run it on other Linux computers. The issue is there are a ton of Perl `.pm` and `.xs` files needed.

I've done the following

- Created a virtual machine that has the same directory structure as the RHEL4 x86_64 Linux computer. I have run into errors this way, namely the `Config.pm` file aborting.
- Used the
  [*PAR Packager* `pp` command](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp)
  to package the Perl script. I keep running into errors when packing it.

What other routes can I take in executing the script on other Linux computers?

Comment: I don't think there's anything specific to x86-64 here.  If there are any compiled binaries involved, you have the same architecture on both machines.  Without any more details, like *what* errors or which perl packages the script depends on, this is unanswerable.  It's not a [mcve] for a debugging question, and the only generic answer is *very* general (what Quentin said).

Comment: Make sure all those modules that the script depends on are installed on the new machine (Easy through your OS's package manager or CPAN. Look into perlbrew or local::lib if you don't have admin rights). Copy the script. Run the script.

Comment: Google for `cpan bundle`. The simplest way would be to use [`autobundle`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ANDK/CPAN-1.60/lib/CPAN.pm#autobundle) to create a bundle of all the modules installed on your source computer, started from the command line with `cpan -a`. You may want to edit the result to remove unnecessary modules, but this list can be installed anywhere with a single command.

Comment: watch the perl version, obviously. You could use local::lib / perlbrew to install the correct perl version locally.